# How do you make a bot go a line down in a message?

Tags: python, discord, bots, message

For some time, I've been working on a discord bot using python. Everything is going great, but there is one problem I haven't found a solution to. In the discord app itself, when typing in a chat, you can hold down the "shift" button and press "enter" to go a line down in chat. How do you make the bot do that in a text? Here is an example of what I'm currently doing

```
      if message.content.startswith('$help'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello. What can I help you with?')
```

There is probably an easy answer since I know it's possible. But I haven't found it.

Comment: Have you tried inserting `\n` in the message where you want a new line to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a newline with the `\n` escape character.

```
  if message.content.startswith('$help'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello.\nWhat can I help you with?')
```

This would print

```
Hello. 
What can I help you with?
```